# How can I export an aws marketplace ami on to s3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-snowball

I need to export an AWS marketplace ami onto the s3 bucket. ec2 Import/export functionality doesn't work as the underlying ami is a marketplace ami
Here is the error that I'm getting

```
An error occurred (NotExportable) when calling the ExportImage operation: The image ID provided (ami-xxxxxx) is a marketplace AMI and is not exportable.
```

I need this AMIto be copied on to the s3 bucket in the snowballEdge device so I can spin up ec2 instances on it.

Comment: I kindly request you to go through this documentation [aws marketplace ami](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ami-store-restore.html) it will give you some technical insights but remember you will incur data transfer costs as well.Keep that in mind,when you're designing your service architecture.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't export an Amazon Machine Image (AMI) image if it contains third-party software.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vm-import/latest/userguide/vmexport_image.html#limits-image-export

> You can't export an image if it contains third-party software provided by AWS. For example, VM Export cannot export Windows or SQL Server images, or any image created from an image in the AWS Marketplace.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway around this Im using the ec2-export for a work AMI (its published in marketplace) just want to pull down for a lab.  Appreciate it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a general workaround to address this issue:

1. Launch an EC2 Instance: Start by launching an EC2 instance using the marketplace AMI you're interested in.
2. Create a Custom AMI:
   Once the instance is up and running, you can customize it according to your needs. After customizing, create a new AMI from this instance. This new AMI will be considered a custom AMI rather than a marketplace AMI.
   To create a new AMI, navigate to the EC2 Dashboard, select the instance, and choose "Actions" > "Image and templates" > "Create image".
3. Export the Custom AMI:
   After creating your custom AMI, you can attempt the export operation again with this new AMI. Since it's not tagged as a marketplace AMI, you should be able to export it.
   Use the `aws ec2 export-image` command with the AMI-ID of the custom AMI you created.

Note: Keep in mind that while this method circumvents the direct export restriction of marketplace AMIs, it's crucial to review and comply with the licensing terms of the software and the AWS Marketplace usage terms. Some software vendors may prohibit such actions or require a separate license for use outside of AWS.